# Starts with N ends in O.... means Yes

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, humor

Just wondering if there is a word (or pair of words) that starts with N and ends with O and actually means Yes (or roughly yes... some sort of synonym).  I thought this might have some humorous applications on occasion.  Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the constructive use and understanding of English.

Comment: Well....  I disagree, who said being humorous in language and using clever puns isn't constructive.

Comment: He's grown out of it now, but my son went through a phase when he often appended **-o** to various "one-word responses". So he (and very likely many others) would have been quite likely to come out with *"**Natcho!**"* for *naturally, surely, yes indeed!*.

Comment: I'm all for being humorous in language and using clever puns.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reminds me of the reported slang of American gangsters from the Prohibition Era. Well, that and Bingo was his name-o. :)

Comment: This closed question has now reached popular question status..... just saying

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most commonly used one that can at least sometimes mean ‘yes’ that I can think of is ***no problemo***.

Comment: Even has "no" in it, very good.

Comment: I love this because it's starts with the word *no*, causing the recipient to do a double take. Great for teasing. Consider this: "Honey, can you babysit the kids tonight?" "No...problemo!"

Comment: You must know this, but others may not realize that this [expression is sometimes used as an instance of "pseudo-Spanish" or Mock Spanish.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problemo) Even beyond the matters of the terminating vowel and associated gender mentioned in the referenced article due to the Greek origin of *problema*, one must add to the expressions’s cringeworthiness the fact that like [other descendants of Latin *non*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non#Descendants), ES *no* is an adverb not an adjective—and therefore corresponds to EN *not*. And *ningún problema* is too long to say.

Answer (score 8):

*Neato*, is at least fairly affirmative. "Do you want to go to the party with me?"

I replied,"Neato!"

neato
a cool little word that is very enjoyable to say. neato can mean "wow, that was really cool!" or "awesome" or it can just be a neato way to say 'neat'.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=neato

Answer (score 5):

"Nod of assent to" starts with N and ends with O. And, it means yes.

Great question. +1

By the way, "not-no" and "no minus no" should mean yes too, if one were to use logic.

Comment: not no is perfect! +1 for the logic

Answer (score 2):

While the following phrases don't necessarily relay an emphatic *yes*, they're (imo) clever ways of pretending to say no but actually implying yes, or at least the possibility of a yes.

- *no to saying no*
- *not gonna say no*
- *not a no*
- *not really a no*
- *non-no*

Answer (score 2):

'No' itself is often used to imply 'yes'. This is particularly common in Cockney.

Two guys in a bar, absolutely soaked.

Guy1: (severely slurred) D'ya wannanother whisky?

Guy2: (equally slurred) Naaaaaaaaaa (falls off bar-stool)

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough one. There are not a lot of words ending in *o*—most of them are borrowed words (*oratorio*), prefixes (*nitro*), or slangish abbreviations (*porno*)—not really the sorts of words that would show up in a very natural phrase that would effectively mean *yes*.

You could go with something like *naturally, kiddo!*, but I suspect that will be stretching the humour more than a little.

See http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/o/.

Answer (score 1):

A *nympho* says yes a lot and I would usually say yes to a nympho.

Comment: LOL.... good one.  But I don't think I'd reply with this as an answer to any question.

Comment: @Squirtle - but if you did, think of the possibilities.

Comment: But what if she had cancer of the nymph glands... a nymphoma?

Answer (score 1):

*"Naturally/Normally/Necessarily so."* could work depending on the circumstance.

*"Naturally bro!"* also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faux-Spanish word (that is, humorously used in English, and designed to sound Spanish, but not actually a real Spanish word) I've heard more than once which might be spelt something like *naturalamondo* or *naturalamundo*, meaning "naturally".

Google has a handful of search results for it showing it coming up on various blogs and Twitter feeds.

Answer (score -1):

Naturally, Daddy-O!

[filler filler filler filler filler]